# IDE that recognizes pandas objects

Tags: python, ide, pandas

Is there a Python IDE that recognizes pandas objects such as Dataframes? If not, is there a plan to develop this?

This is done well in RStudio for R. There dataframes are listed and can be viewed outside of the terminal. Spyder's object viewer (as one example) does not pick up on Dataframes from pandas. It should be possible to view the dimensions, column names and other useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using spyder and it is the closest I have found to something like Rstudio. It also integrates with Ipython!

[Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about a pandas-centric IDE but the main difference between python and R is that python is a general purpose object with so many dynamic features that is very difficult to make and IDE which introspects all the objects while you're coding. One useful approach for the python community is to use [IPython](http://ipython.org/) as interactive shell, it works really nice with `pandas`, `matplotlib`, `numpy` and `scipy`.